# Diatomaceous earth use for bed bugs

Tags: pest-control

I saw a post about using diatomaceous earth on here from 2013.... Did it ever work?  Having issues that have me in tears here. Have tried bombs. .. sprays. .. feel like I am slowly killing us with poison.

Comment: The only person that can tell you if it worked is the person who posted the original question. You need to ask them that as a comment in their question.

Answer (score 1):

Diatomaceous earth is used by bed bug control professionals as one tool among many, but the best recourse is professional help. If you have an home owner's association or are renting, they should be alerted and have funds to cover some of the costs.

**TALK TO A BEG BUG PROFESSIONAL. Initial consultations are usually free.**

Otherwise, additional basic starting tools are:

1. Mattress & box encasements (critical to install properly and watch for tears)
2. Traps for your bed frame legs
3. Spray bottle of 92% alcohol to kill bugs/eggs
4. Heat.

   1. Laundering will kill bugs guaranteed
   2. Put your items in a tightly tied garbage bag, leave in your car for an entire day in the summer sun (goal: a few hours of 120+ degrees F).

**TALK TO A BEG BUG PROFESSIONAL. Initial consultations are usually free.**

Comment: I am going to seek help when I have a couple Grand laying around. For now I need control or at least a stop gap.  Any more ideas please post.  I am having a nervous breakdown

Comment: You basically have to revamp your life into a highly disciplined and careful method. Quarantine; clean; control what goes in and out of your house; have a different set of clothes for going out, for being in the house, for being in bed. Track bites. Etc... Also: http://reddit.com/r/bedbugs